# Get row data from Sheet1 then put it in another UserForm

Tags: excel, userform, vba

Excel 2013 with VBA

UserForm1 shows a TextBox and a ListBox.
It will display the name based on the ID in TextBox.
I wanted to display all the information for that specific person and then display it in a 2nd UserForm.

[image: Screenshot]

Here's my code so far:

```
Private Sub txtID_Change()

Dim x, dict
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cnt As Long

    Set mySheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ListBox1.Clear
    x = mySheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    If Application.CountIf(mySheet.Columns(2), txtID.Text) > 0 Then
        For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
            If x(i, 2) = txtID.Text Then
                dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = ""
            End If
        Next i
        ListBox1.List = dict.keys
    Else
        ListBox1.AddItem "Match not found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Could be a `ListBox1_Change()` event that shows `UserForm2` in non-modal mode.

Comment: I see..i don't know how to come up with that..but I will try.

Comment: Not sure where your code resides (in the Form or in a Module), but you can run code from anywhere. If your code is in a Module you can simply update both Forms at the same time by providing explicit references to the Form you are updating. Form1.ListBox1.AddItem "item" ... or ... Form2.Textbox1.Text = "something".

Comment: Thank you so much..my code resides in UserForm1. I will try to put the code in module.